# Can someone explain me what [](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; } means?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

In the following example code of the STL algorithm `std::all_of`,

What does '[](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; }' mean?

```
int main() { 

    std::vector<int> v{10, 2, 4, 6}; 

    if (std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i){ return i % 2 == 0; })) { 
        std::cout << "All numbers are even\n"; 
    } 
    else{
        std::cout << "All numbers are not even\n"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) that checks if `i` is even or not. It will return true if `i` is even, otherwise false.

It's logic is equivalent to this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool isEven(int i) {
  return i % 2 == 0;
}

int main() { 

    std::vector<int> v{10, 2, 4, 6}; 

    if (std::all_of(v.begin(), v.end(), isEven)) { 
        std::cout << "All numbers are even\n"; 
    } 
    else{
        std::cout << "All numbers are not even\n"; 
    }
}
```

Output:

> All numbers are even

---

Note: This is lambda method is a free function, and it does *not* capture anything.

PS: That lambda method has nothing to do with STL.

Comment: Looks like I still need to study these lambda functions, thank you

Comment: @Lorenzo the λ methods can come in handy, think about it abstractly as an anonymous method, check them out and have fun... Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way! :)